# %FF encoding between java and js

Tags: javascript, java, encoding, decode

I have a jsp that prints the contents of a file:

```
out.println(URLEncoder.encode(fileContents))
```

Then, in js, I decode the result with

```
decodeURIComponent(result)
```

But, I get an error on:

```
%FF
```

> URIError: URI malformed at decodeURIComponent...

Is there a different way I should be doing this?

Comment: Why URL encoding in the first place - are you putting this _into_ a URL context anywhere? If you just want to output data so that JavaScript can parse & use it - then you should encode it as JSON.

Comment: When the compiler warns you that [a method is deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String)), don’t just ignore the warning.  Pass UTF-8 as the charset argument.

Comment: I'm encoding it because the files contain html or xml or any number of script types, and I want to see the content of the file, not what they produce. I'm using encode, because I saw it somewhere else. If you have a better idea, please suggest it.

Comment: Re _"If you have a better idea, please suggest it"_, the user _did_ suggest a better idea: _"Pass UTF-8 as the charset argument"_. So try changing your call from `out.println(URLEncoder.encode(fileContents))` to `out.println(URLEncoder.encode(fileContents), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`. That may or may not resolve the issue, but the user was constructively attempting to assist you. If that change doesn't help, update your question with sample data for `fileContents` that will allow others to attempt to reproduce/resolve your problem. Is "%FF" part of the data you are attempting to encode/decode?

Comment: _"I'm encoding it because the files contain html or xml or any number of script types, and I want to see the content of the file, not what they produce."_ - that makes little sense to begin with, since you are _decoding_ it again on the receiving end. If you want to _see_ HTML/XML tags on your page, instead of having the browser try to interpret them _as_ HTML - then you need to apply proper _HTML encoding_, not URL encoding.